# Linux BASH memory leak when redirecting stdio

Tags: linux, bash, memory-leaks

I've got a memory leak *somewhere*, but it doesn't appear to be related to my program.  I'm making this bold statement based on the fact that once my program terminates, either by normal means, seg-faulting, or aborting, the memory isn't recovered.  If my program were the culprit, I would assume the MMU would recover everything, but this doesn't appear to be the case.

The leak only comes into play when I redirect stdout (in BASH version 2.05 or 4) to a file, as in this is okay:

```
# my-program
```

but this isn't:

```
# my-program > /mnt/sda1/log-output.txt
```

The rate at which I'm printing to the screen is < 2Kb/sec.  (The file is on a USB key).

Any ideas?

A related question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545533/arm-linux-memory-leak-can-a-user-program-retain-memory-after-terminating).

Comment: And how exactly do you know you got a leak?

Comment: At first I knew when I got a segmentation fault, and 40 of the 45 Megs of RAM was missing (its an embedded system).  I rebooted and relauched the program and monitored the memory with this command `for ((c=1;c;)) do cat /proc/meminfo && sleep 1; done | awk '/MemFree:/ { if ($2 < min || min == 0) min = $2; if ($2 > max || max == 0) max = $2; printf("%s\t%d (%d,%d)\n", $1, $2, min, max) }'`

Comment: Did you check the figure for your Cached field? Writing to a file could certainly add to your cache. This will reduce the MemFree, but can be reclaimed as necessary, so you haven't lost any memory as such.

Comment: does it fail with any other shell? I can't see how bash could be doing this, being as it's parsing a file name, opening the file, and forking you program with the descriptor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MemFree alone says nearly nothing.

Linux's block layer caches a lot.

You can see how much is being used for filesystem (and other) caches in the same /proc/meminfo you have mentioned.

Comment: Alllll righty then! I looked at the other fields in the /proc/meminfo and saw that the "Active:" and "Cached:" fields climb significantly.  I probably don't have memory leak.