# ARM/Linux memory leak: Can a user program retain memory after terminating?

Tags: linux, memory-leaks

I've got a memory leak *somewhere*, but it doesn't appear to be related to my program.  I'm making this bold statement based on the fact that once my program terminates, either by seg-faulting, exitting, or aborting, the memory isn't recovered.  If my program were the culprit, I would assume the MMU would recover everything, but this doesn't appear to be the case.

My question is:

*On a small Linux system (64 Mb Ram) running a program that uses only stack memory and a few calls to `malloc()`, what causes can I look too see memory being run down and stay down once my program terminates?*

A related question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545530/linux-bash-memory-leak-when-redirecting-stdio):

---

This all started when after code in question was directing its stdout, stderr to a file.  After a few hours it aborted with a "Segmentation Fault".  A quick (naive?) look at /proc/meminfo showed that there wasn't much available memory, so I assumed something was leaking.

Comment: Can you please explain what you are seeing that makes you believe that a program is retaining memory after terminating.  I'm guessing you are misinterpreting some other situation.

Comment: That's my guess too.  I was recently pointed to looking at memory being cached by the block layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I don't have a memory leak (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545530/linux-bash-memory-leak-when-redirecting-stdio)) but it does lead me to some new questions...

---

It turns out that writing to block devices can use a quite a pile of physical memory; in my system there was only 64 Meg, so writing hundreds of Megs to a USB drive was increasing the cached, active and inactive memory pools quite a bit.

These memory pools are immediately released to the Free memory pool when the device is dismounted.

The exact cause of my segmentation fault remains a small mystery, but I know it's occurence can be reduced by understanding the virtual memory resources better, particularly around the use of Block devices.